# How to check for presence of a layer in a scapy packet?

Tags: python, scapy

How do I check for the presence of a particular layer in a scapy packet? For example, I need to check the src/dst fields of an IP header, how do I know that a particular packet actually has an IP header (as opposed to IPv6 for instance).

My problem is that when I go to check for an IP header field, I get an error saying that the IP layer doesn't exist. Instead of an IP header, this particular packet had IPv6.

```
pkt = Ether(packet_string)
if pkt[IP].dst == something:
  # do this
```

My error occurs when I try to reference the IP layer. How do I check for that layers existence before attempting to manipulate it?

Thanks!

Comment: So what if an exception is thrown? Just catch it and recast it to what you now know it is.

Comment: While that works, is that something you'd normally want to do? I mean using exceptions to handle cases that aren't really 'exceptional'. Of course, that is a question on its own. I am going to leave this open for a while to see if there is an actual scapy solution. Thanks though!

Comment: It's quite Pythonic. The moniker is, "it is better to ask forgiveness than permission." The Python library itself (and its C counterpart) uses the same exception-handling-as-control-structure idiom.

Comment: Well, sounds good to me. I am new to Python so I hadn't had much exposure to this. At least adding the code in was simple, as are many things in Python. At any rate, I am still going to wait for responses specific to scapy, but I appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should try the `in` operator. It returns `True` or `False` depending if the layer is present or not in the `Packet`.

```
root@u1010:~/scapy# scapy
Welcome to Scapy (2.2.0-dev)
>>> load_contrib("ospf")
>>> pkts=rdpcap("rogue_ospf_hello.pcap")
>>> p=pkts[0]
>>> IP in p
True
>>> UDP in p
False
>>>
root@u1010:~/scapy#
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate Santa's insight as well, because that worked just fine. However I knew there must have been some way of checking this. Thanks to you both!

Comment: i got error : ```IndexError: Layer [Radius] not found``` while try to import Radius layer, how fix it?

Answer (score 18):

For completion I thought I would also mention the `haslayer` method.

```
>>> pkts=rdpcap("rogue_ospf_hello.pcap") 
>>> p=pkts[0]
>>> p.haslayer(UDP)
0
>>> p.haslayer(IP)
1
```

Hope that helps as well.

Comment: Yeah, this is also what is suggested in Scapy's documentation.

Comment: [Latest Scapy socs say that `haslayer` is superceded by `cls in self` method](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.packet.html?highlight=haslayer#scapy.packet.Packet.haslayer).